# XMLHttpRequest Access-Control-Allow-Origin fails for image first few times

Tags: javascript, http-headers, cross-domain

I use this code around 20 times to load images from my external server:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', uri, true); //uri is the image link
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(event){
```

In the directory where these images are stored i have placed a htaccess file with the following content:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This code works fine except for the first 4 images to be retreived.. I get the following error:

```
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How is this possible? There is no real difference between the images and the code is not changing? :\

This is what i see in Chrome for the failing image:

```
Request URL:http://www.ardennenbed.nl/sitemanager/fotos/1329589074.jpg
Request Headers
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/app/www/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
```

This is what i see in Chrome for the working image:

```
Request URL:http://www.ardennenbed.nl/sitemanager/fotos/1280247085.gif
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:www.ardennenbed.nl
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/app/www/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:close
Content-Length:8486
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Thu, 10 Jan 2013 12:19:20 GMT
ETag:"8192d2-2126-eb0e53c0"
Last-Modified:Wed, 09 Jan 2013 18:06:15 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
```

Please help me!

Comment: My first request to `http://www.ardennenbed.nl/sitemanager/fotos/1329589074.jpg` gives me `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*, *`. Could it be a cache problem (browser, local proxy, server proxy, etc.) ? Did you try adding a timestamp to the url ? The `*, *` looks a little strange to me.

Comment: deleted browser history and it works now, i feel so stupid.. thanks for the solution!

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for the confirmation.